# SqlServer Types error at build time

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, build

I am working on a project in which we use the Geo types form SqlServer.

For this purpose I had to add some DLLs in the solution that gets copied through the build process:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

This works quite great on my machine but then the guys in my team have build errors because of this.
We are using our local IIS to host the solution and once IIS has started they can't build anymore.

Tho only solution we found now is to restart the app pool (but honestly we're just typing iisreset)

Here is a part of the error message (I stripped out the solution/project name)

```
Error     15         Could not copy "C:\Workspace\code-...Error 15  Could not copy "C:\Workspace\My-Awesome-Project\Web\MyAwesomeProject.Web\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.1\nativeBinaries\x64\msvcr100.dll" to "bin\SqlServerTypes\x64\msvcr100.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
```

I believe that there is a difference between my computer and the one from my colleagues but we could not point at the one difference that might have an influence on the problem.

Any clue?

Comment: When you installed Visual Studio, did you install the SQL server component? It is not installed by default.

Comment: Are you talking about Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools. Just found this in the About Visual Studio window.

Comment: Do you try to execute SQL expression via Visual Studio environment or via SQL server?

Comment: Apparently my colleagues have the Data tools installed too. About the SQL Expression, I do not believe so. Just to be sure, can you give an example of expression? I think the only thing we do is to copy the dlls to the bin folder that is actually being used by IIS

Comment: @GeorgesLegros, did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue and looking for an answer.

Comment: Not at all... If you can find a solution,please come back in here...

Answer (score 0):

Your app pool keeps a lock on those DLLs. Stop the App Pool before building.

Comment: Well the thing is that I do not have to do that on my computer ever. All my co-workers have to... So I thought it could be something installed on my machine that is not installed on their machines. So far we did not nailed it down.